# Why do I need to click the button twice for submitting when using Ajax Panel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, updatepanel

I am using `asp:UpdateProgress` control to show progress during a button click. I am using telerik controls to ajaxify the submit button. The code sample is below:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel4" runat="server">
  <div class="customButton">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSave" OnClientClick="return Page_ClientValidate();" 
                    runat="server" OnClick="lbtnSave_Click" CausesValidation="true">
      <img src="../admin/images/icons/16x16/save.png" /> 
      Save 
    </asp:LinkButton>
  <div class="customButton">
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

My issue:

When I surround the button with the `telerik:RadAjaxPanel`, I have to click on the button twice. If I remove the panel, the button submits in one click. Is this happening because of the OnClientClick or one of the other LinkButton attributes or because of the surrounding `telerik:RadAjaxPanel`? Please help.

Comment: I have changed the LinkButton to Button, and still the problem persists. I have also tried removing the OnClientClick attribute; that did not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this issue is related to a page-refresh-detection logic on the page. With the RadAjaxPanel, the first button click caused the logic to think that its a page refresh - consuquently, the button was not submitted.

Comment: Can you please expand on this more? I'm encountering the same issue and your answer doesn't make sense to me.